# Non functioning Prestashop box

Tags: prestashop

Please take a look at the following images,
I have a problem with my online website. At the step 4 of order process, the box which has to be picked up does not display itself.

Consequently, customers give up the card because they can not go further this step.

Can someone explain me how to show the box up ?

Thank you by advance.

Best regards,
Elliot

[Pre-purchase step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XXcHC.png)

[No display box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zN6Fh.png)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing an image in your theme:

https://elick.fr/themes/jms_furniture/img/jquery/uniform/sprite.png

This is the image from the original theme http://prestashopthemes.joommasters.com/jms_furniture/themes/jms_furniture/img/jquery/uniform/sprite.png.

This sprite is called in your uniform.default.css file in line 13.

[image]